# How to convert a dictionary in Python from a string to an array filled with zeros using numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a dictionary

`A = {"D":[ "SSSS", "SSSS", "SSSS", "SSSS" ]}`

I want to convert it to an array filled with zeros for example:

`table=np.zeros(A)`

`print (table)`

This result is giving me an error

`TypeError: expected sequence object with len >= 0 or a single integer`
Tell me how to fix this situation?Thanks

Comment: Could you add the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that all the strings inside `A` are of the same length:

```
import numpy as np

A = {"D":[ "SSSS", "SSSS", "SSSS", "SSSS" ]}
n = len(A['D'][0])
Z = np.zeros(shape=(n, n))
Z
```

**Output**

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Cheers